# Notepad++ alternatives for Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04

I just switched to Ubuntu as my OS and i am asking is their any alternative for Notepad++ for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

By default Ubuntu shold come with GEdit if using the default Gnome environment or Kate with the KDE environment. There is also Pluma which is available from the repository. If you're really set on Notepad++ you can install WINE and then run it directly.